# How do I use the current folder name without a path as a variable in automator in Mac?

Tags: macos, variables, directory, automator

I am using Mac OSX 10.8.3.

I have a workflow in Automator set up that is as follows:

1. Ask for Finder Items
2. Get Folder Contents
3. Make Sequential
4. Move Finder Items

The purpose of the workflow is to automate renaming a bunch of photos that I have saved in folders then move them to an new folder.

I want to grab the foldername and stick it in a variable and use that variable in the "new name box" in the Make Sequential section of the work flow (see attached) image.

How do I grab just the folder name and assign it to a variable.  My example has a variable called "FolderName"

Here is a screenshot
[image: screen shot]

Comment: I think you will have more luck with your question on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Where/how are you picking this new folder from

Answer (score 16):

This works in testing:

1. **Ask for finder Items** - set type to Folders.
2. **Set Value of Variable** - this will be the **path** to the folder taken from action **1**.
3. **Run Shell Script** - set the Pass input : as argument. And use ***/usr/bin/basename "$1"*** as the command line to get the folder name
4. **Set Value of Variable** - this will be the **folderName** of the folder taken
   from action **3**.
5. **Get Value of Variable** - set the Variable it obtains the value of to **path**

   5a. set action **5** to ignore input from the above action **4** -  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse click on the action Title to get the Contextual Menu
6. **Get Folder Contents** - get the contents of the folder at the **path** passed on from Action **5**
7. **Rename Finder Items** - Set to Make Sequential and new name = the **folderName** Variable

[image]

You can add your Move actions after as you wish.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `Run Shell Script Action`, with the following code:

```bsh
echo ${1##*/}
```

and `Pass input:` set to `as arguments`.

[image]

This will filter the passed input, giving only the file basename as output.

You should put this step before the action that sets `FolderName` variable.

Answer (score 1):

another short version to get a folder name and assign it to a variable.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set currentDir to target of Finder window 1 as alias
    set posixDir to POSIX path of currentDir
    -- set myShell to "touch \"" & posix & "\"readme.txt"
    -- set result to (do shell script myShell)
end tell
```

[image: screenshot]